# Standard ML exceptions and resources

Tags: exception, resources, ml

I would like to release a resource when any exception is raised during the usage of the resource.

In C++ this task is easy: I put the release into the destructor, which gets called automatically, whatever happens. In Java one uses the 'finally' clause. What is the practice for this same task in Standard ML?

I tried to catch all exception with a variable pattern 'e' and re-raise it:

```
datatype FileReadResult = FileReadOkay of string | FileReadError

fun read_file (file_path_string : string) : FileReadResult =
    let
        val istream = TextIO.openIn file_path_string
            (* this file is my resource *)
    in
        TextIO.closeIn istream;
        FileReadOkay "" (* the content of the file will go here *)
        handle e => (TextIO.closeIn istream; raise e)
    end
    handle Io => FileReadError
```

My compiler (MLton) accepts it, but because I am new in ML, I ask here for some assurance that this is really the right thing | best practice to do.

As this is a common design pattern, I created the below utility function to express it:

```
(* Uses the given resource in the given way while releasing it if any exception occurs. *)
fun use_resource (resource : 'Resource) (releaser : 'Resource -> unit) (usage : unit -> 'Result) : 'Result = 
    let
        val r = usage ()
    in
        releaser resource;
        r
    end
    handle e => (releaser resource; raise e)
```

This function plays the same role as the 'using' feature in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the usual pattern, with two caveats:

1. The inner `handle` is around the `FileReadOkay ""` only in your code, which won't ever throw. You want to put parentheses around a larger part of the code, so that the handler applies to all of it.
2. Your outer handler catches `Io`. I think you mean `IO.Io _` here, otherwise you will catch *every* exception (because `Io` is just a random fresh variable).

You can also try to abstract it into a function if it occurs frequently. Something along the lines of

```
(* withTextFile : string -> (TextIO.instream -> 'a) -> 'a
fun withTextFile name f =
    let
        val is = TextIO.openIn name
    in
        (f is before TextIO.closeIn is)
        handle e => (TextIO.closeIn is; raise e)
    end
```

(The infix operator `before` evaluates its left-hand and right-hand expression and returns the result of the former). Use it like:

```
fun echo file = withTextFile file (fn is => print(TextIO.inputAll is))
```

Comment: Especially thanks for the warning about the Io <-> IO.Io _ error.
This "variable pattern" feature of the semantics seems very error-prone - if i make a little typo, then the compiler will not warn and will do something totally different silently. I guess I always should qualify the type in order to avoid it being interpreted as a variable pattern.

Comment: I agree that this feature is a bit error-prone, at least with exception handlers (with normal patterns, such an error will usually result a "redundant match" warning anyway). I prefer s.th like the OCaml/Haskell solution that distinguishes constructors and variables by case.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: *The Standard ML Basis Library*, after describing its conventions for letter-case in value identifiers (page 3), states that compilers could use these conventions to detect this exact mistake and issue a warning for it. It's too bad that compilers don't seem to have taken the hint!

Comment: @ruakh, yes, though there is at least one compiler (Alice ML) that issues warnings about naming convention violations -- which I know because I wrote its front-end. :)